# Fastest iPhone Blit Routine?

Tags: iphone, drawing, performance, blit

I have a `UIView` subclass onto which I need to blit a `UIImage`. There are several ways to skin this cat depending on which series of APIs you prefer to use, and I'm interested in the fastest. Would it be `UIImage`'s `drawAtPoint` or `drawRect`? Or perhaps the C-based CoreGraphics routines, or something else? I have no qualms about altering my source image data format if it'll make the blitting that much faster.

To describe my situation my app has anywhere from ~10 to ~200 small `UIView`s (64x64), a subset of which will need to be redrawn based on user interaction. My current implementation is a call to `drawAtPoint` inside my `UIView` subclass' `drawRect` routine. If you can think of a better way to handle this kind of scenario, I'm all ears (well, eyes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While not a "blit" at all, given the requirements of the problem (many small images with various state changes) I was able to keep the different states to redraw in their own separate `UIImageView` instances, and just showed/hid the appropriate instance given the state change.

Answer (score 3):

Using an OpenGL view may be fastest of all.  Keep an age cache of images (or if you know a better way to determine when certain images can be removed from the cache, by all means use that) and preload as many images as you can while the app is idle.  It should be very quick, with almost no Objective-C calls involved (just `-draw`)

Answer (score 1):

Since CALayer is lightweight and fast I would get a try.

Thierry

Answer (score 1):

The fastest blit implementation you are going to find is in my AVAnimator library, it contains an ARM asm implementation of a blit for a CoreGraphics buffer, have a look at the source. The way you could make use of it would be to create a single graphics context, the size of the whole screen, and then blit your specific image changes into this single graphics context, then create a UIImage from that and set it as the image of a UIImageView. That would involve 1 GPU upload per refresh, so it will not depend on how many images you render into the buffer. But, you will likely not need to go that low level. You should first try making each 64x64 image into a CALayer and then update each layer with the contents of an image that is the exact size of the layer 64x64. The only tricky thing is that you will want to decompress each of your original images if they come from PNG or JPEG files. You do that by creating another pixel buffer and rendering the original image into the new pixel buffer, that way all the PNG or JPEG decompression is done *before* you start setting CALayer contents.